# Does the set of all $n \times n$ Householder matrices form a vector space

Tags: vector-spaces

Let us define a Householder matrix as $H=I-2(w w^T)/(w^T w)$, where $w$ is $n \times 1$ and $H$ is $n \times n$ with $n \geq 2$ respectively. 
I know that to prove a vector space, we need to show the following properties (here $a$ and $b$ are real values, $v$ and $w$ are $n \times 1$ non-vectors):

- $v+w=w+v$
- $a(b w)=(ab) w$
- $1 w=w$
- $a(v+w)=av+aw$
- $(a+b)w=aw+bw$

But the above equations seem trivially true for all the matrices. I'm afraid there must be something that I misunderstand. 
Could anybody help?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the zero matrix a Householder matrix?

Comment: Im not sure if zero matrix could be a householder matrix, but in this question we have the constraint that n>=2, hence there is no zero matrix.

Comment: Huh? The zero matrix is the matrix whose entries are all zero. There certainly is such a matrix, for all $n$. And an axiom of vector spaces is that every vector space must have an additive identity element; for vector spaces of matrices, that's the zero matrix.

Comment: Any thoughts, Ben, on my comment, or on the answer from 7530?

Comment: Yes, I really appreciate you and 7530's suggestions. Gerry you are right, a vector space has to contain the zero matrix. In this question, I tried to multiply the householder matrix by vectors w and v respectively, here w is perpendicular to v. So what I got is that the householder matrix is nonsingular, that is, there is no zero matrix. So I conclude that the householder matrices cannot form a vector space. Please correct me if Im wrong. And thank you so much for your follow-up!

Answer (score 1):

You're asking several questions about vector spaces, and this one is a bit harder than the others, so instead of giving you the full answer, let me suggest a program of inquiry that will help you figure this one out on your own:

1. What happens if you multiply $H$ by the vector $w$?
2. What happens if you multiply $H$ by any vector perpendicular to $w$?
3. What can you conclude about the geometric meaning of the matrix $H$? What does it do to vectors?
4. Does your answer to #3 tell you anything about algebraic properties $H$ must satisfy?
5. Now try some examples: pick some elements in your set of Householder matrices, and compute their sum, and check if they satisfy the properties you identified in #4. If several examples seem to work, try to prove the vector space properties algebraically. And of course, if an example doesn't work, you have a counterexample.